# Trying to get which points of a sf object are within another sf object with sf_within

Tags: r, spatial

I have a sf dataframe looking with boat track points that looks like this:

```
sf_object<-c("Time"="13:05, 16:04, 15:16, "geometry"="POINT(-125.25 48.3), POINT(-125.13 48.8), POINT (-125.139 48 83)).
```

I have another sf object converted from a shapefile that looks like this:

```
border<-c("Area"=894756335954, "geometry"=POLYGON ((-129.95 55.925, -129.8 55.67, -121.57 46.78, -121.68 46.92)))
```

I should add that both object are on the same coordinates projection system (WGS84).

When I plot them, it looks like that, so you can see that the boat tracks go from one side to the other of the border (the gray area is the polygon).
[image]
Now I am trying to know which points of my sf_object are within the border polygon, and which ones are outside. I am using the following code to do so (and converting the results into a logical vector):

```
sf_object$InCanada<-st_within(border_sf$geometry,sf_object$geometry, sparse=F)%>%diag()
```

But then it tells me that all the points are on one side of the border, which is incorrect.

```
> unique(sf_object$InCanada)
[1] TRUE
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's hard to tell without including reproducible data, but I think your problem is the order of args to `st_within`. You want the points first and polygon second with how your situation is set up, since you'll never have your border polygon contained within a point from the boat position.

Comment: This answer might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67725046/9022665

Comment: Your lines describing what `sf_object` and `border` are look incomplete and don't run to make valid R objects. Usually you'd have a spatial data frame with points, and a spatial dataframe with polygons, and `st_within(pts, polys)` will return a ragged list of the polygons each point is in. If you only have only polygon then testing for the list length == 1 is a point-in-polygon test, but until you describe the data more clearly I'm not sure we can give code solutions.